# PhP, auto close console window when the batch file ran

Tags: php, batch-file, console

I have a batch file, say:

```
DIR *.*
anotherprogram.exe
EXIT
```

and from php:

```
exec('start batch.bat');
```

I want to hang up the running while batch file running and continue... its almost ok, but the opened CMD window wont close, I have to do it manually. How to auto close?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand this correctly the php window is not closing after it has run the batch file, if this is the case try using `exit;`

Comment: I added, its in the example, still wont close

Comment: In your example you are using EXIT in your batch file, not the php file.